# web3 modal with pure vanilla js in 2023?

Tags: web3js

It was very easy with web3modal v1. But now I couldn't find any example how to implement web3modal v3 with vanilla js without any frameworks. Or any other web3 modal, doesn't matter if it is web3modal.

Is there any web3 modal that supports pure vanilla js without any frameworks?